# Formatting tooltip for everviz

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, tooltip

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6njf.png)

This is a question specific to everviz/highcharts...

I'm new to Everviz and know very little javascript, but I'm trying to format tooltips to reflect all the data in my Everviz table, but I can only seem to show one of the two categories at any one time (as shown in the screenshot) - Is there a way i can build a tooltip that as the percentages on its own line below (eg: 14%) and is there a way I can do this that is reusable with other data?

Here's the code for this chart (the comments are my attempts to make sense of the code as i see it with my little to no knowledge )

```
Highcharts.merge(true, options, {
  
/* CHART HEADER TITLE */  
    "title": {
    "text": "Xxxxxxxxx",
    "align": "Left",
    "x": 70,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Lato",
      "color": "#000",
      "fontSize": "18px",
      "fontWeight": "bold",
      "fontStyle": "normal"
    },
    "useHTML": true
  },

  
  /* SUB HEADER / STRAPLINE */
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "Xxxxxxx",
    "align": "left",
    "x": 70,
    "style": {
      "color": "#666666",
      "fontFamily": "Lato",
      "fontSize": "12px"
    },
    "useHTML": true
  },
  
  
  
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "allowPointSelect": true,
      "states": {
        "select": {
          /* selected slice colour */
          "color": "#eda647",
          "borderColor": "black" /* */,
          "dashStyle": "dot"
        }
      },
     
      "label": {
        "enabled": false
      },

      
      
 /* SHOW CHART DATA LABELS
 =================================================*/
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "color": "#333333"
      },
      "stacking": "normal",
      "animation": false
    }
  },

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* CHART DATA
  ================================================*/
  
  "data": {
     /* Retrieval of table header row data ( "csv":... ), followed by the xAxis data and the associated  values in that column ( 3 column example: \n2013;2013;#;#;#) */
  "csv": "\"Economy\";\"Operating assets\";\"Percent\"\n\"SERBIA\";189;14.8\n\"EGYPT\";179;14\n\"TURKEY\";93;7.2\n\"TUNISIA\";76;6\n\"GEORGIA\";75;5.8\n\"BULGARIA\";63;4.9\n\"UZBEKISTAN\";62;4.8\n\"KAZAKHSTAN\";59;4.6\n\"ROMANIA\";55;4.3\n\"BELARUS\";52;4\n\"UKRAINE\";48;3.8\n\"MOROCCO\";41;3.2\n\"LATVIA\";38;3\n\"ARMENIA\";32;2.5\n\"KYRGYZ REPUBLIC\";32;2.5\n\"MOLDOVA\";30;2.3\n\"POLAND\";27;2.1\n\"MONGOLIA\";27;2.1\n\"BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA\";23;1.8\n\"KOSOVO\";20;1.6\n\"CROATIA\";18;1.4\n\"NORTH MACEDONIA\";17;1.4\n\"JORDAN\";11;0.8\n\"TAJIKISTAN\";6;0.5\n\"ALBANIA\";3;0.3\n\"AZERBAIJAN\";2;0.1",
    "googleSpreadsheetKey": false,
    "googleSpreadsheetWorksheet": false,
    "seriesMapping": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "label": 2
      },
    
    ]
  },

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  /* CANDIDATE for removal

  "chart": {
    "type": "column",
    "polar": false,
    "style": {
      "fontFamily": "Lato",
      "fontSize": "12px"
    }
  },
  

  

  /* CHART TYPE PER COLUMN OF DATA 
  ================================================*/
  "series": [
    {
      "turboThreshold": 0,
      /*first colour in the 'APPEARANCE'tab array of colours */
      "_colorIndex": 0,
      "_symbolIndex": 0,
      /* custom index colour - will default to array order if no value is assigned */
      "color": "",

      
/*  Reflect the values of referenced column in 'series'*/
      "tooltip": {
        "pointFormat": "{series.name}: <b>€{point.y} million</b><br>",

        "valueDecimals": 1
      },
      
      
/* PRIMARY CHART TYPE DECLEARED HERE..(LINE/COLUMN, BAR etc ..)
==================================================*/
      "type": "pie"
    },
   

  ],
  
/* CHART LEGEND
================================================*/
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false,
    "verticalAlign": "bottom",
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "floating": false
  },
 
 
  
/* COLOURS ASSIGNED ( FROM THE AR_SR CHART COLOUR SUITE ) 
  TO THE CHART AS SEEN IN THE 'APPEARANCE'tab  */  
    "colors": [
    "#20536A",
    "#3487AB",
    "#A5D1E4",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    "#DFDFDF",
    
    /* AR_SR CHART COLOUR SUITE VALUES
    =====================================
    
    B1 "#20536A",
    B2 "#3487AB",
    B3 "#A5D1E4",
    O1 "#C95717”,
    O2 "#D67311”,
    O3 "#EDA647”,
    O4 "#F6CE9B”,
    R1 "#B53260”,
    R2 "#D5678E”,
    G1 "#3F3F3F”,
    G2 "#454545”,
    G3 "#9D9D9C”,
    G4 "#CCCCCC”,
    G5 "#DFDFDF"  
    
    */
      
     
  ],
  

});
```

Comment: Please past your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ or using the code-snippet - see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/12511801) for more details - this is because I can't reproduce your issue with the settings added in your question.

Comment: Hello, if you're not sure how to create a JSFiddle, please post the share link for the chart. I'll have a look anyway, but appreciate something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I applaud your efforts in trying to solve this yourself, and will give you the solution, followed by the explanation:

```js
Highcharts.merge(true, options, {
  "tooltip": {
    "useHTML": true,
    "formatter": function () {
      return `<small>${this.point.name}</small>
             <br>${this.series.name}: <b>€${this.y} million</b>
             <br>Percentage: <b>${Math.round(this.percentage)}%</b>`
    },
    // Insert the rest of your config here
});
```

---

**what one does**

The first thing I did was I hopped on Google and searched for something like "Highcharts tooltip content", and I found a forum post and also the for it: [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip) for it, specifically the #formatting bit.

That told us we need to use `tooltip.formatter` with a function^1 that returns the content we want. Unfortunately we can't use rich text editing, but we know HTML so that does not matter. So we claim the content looks like this

```html
<small text>
  {point.name}<- put the name of the thing here
<end small text>
{series.name}: <bold>€{y} million<end bold>
Percentage: <bold>{percentage}%</bold>
```

**making it dynamic with JavaScript**

Notice I changed the formatting a bit here? Most of the noise you see, is because we need a way to tell what's a value that's there, and what's a value we want to *substitute in*. So when we say `${this.series.name}` or `{series.name}`, we don't literally mean it, we mean to substitute the contents inside `{` and `}` --- the former is how JS wants it, even if it's uglier. The `this` is just something that you need to refer to the value in a function.

**formatting it with HTML**

The value inside brackets are also substituted in the output, but not as values, but rather have a meaning with a stylistic side-effect.

**fitting the pieces together with JavaScipt objects**

An object is just keys and values, written in a standard way: `"key": value`, and separated by commas, note that a value can be its a collection of keys and values on its own!

**what's in a word?**

There are some things left aside that I will briefly explain:

- `Highcharts.merge(true, options, {...}` means to merge the default Highcharts configuration, `options`, with the values you specify in `{...}`.
- `useHTML` means to render the text with HTML and not SVG, which means you can use `<small>`.
- `<small>` is an HTML element for small text, likewise is `<b>` for bold text, and `<br/>` a new line.
- `Math.round` is the rounded percentage, because out-of-the box it looks like 3.141592653589793238462643 -- which we just say 3.
- Functions can be read about [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

**Footnotes**

1. Our function does not take a value as input, it always returns the same thing. Meaning it would not need to be a function, and you can think of the stuff after `return` to be the only part of significance.